# EditText with AutoComplete in email fields

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-edittext

My question is quite straight. I want to have an `EditText` field with `AutoComplete` and `AutoCorrect` enabled.

The problem is, AutoComplete and AutoCorrect do not work when we use input type as `textEmailAddress`:

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress|textAutoComplete|textAutoCorrect"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/email"/>
```

I know emails shouldn't have autocorrect, and my `EditText` is not an email. But, it does have the `@` symbol in every case - which is why I'm using the `inputType` as `textEmailAddress` so that I could directly get the `@` at the first pop-up of keyboard.